# Laravel API using vhosts return 404

Tags: php, laravel, apache, api

I am using Laravel 5.8 and make a simple API route

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'test';
});
```

But when i access from browser or postman: `map-service-api.test/api/test`. It returns 404 page
I tried `dd(123)` in api.php file. It worked (browser shows 123). I also tried `php artisan route:list` the routes api/test also shows. I tried clear cache but it not work.
Thank all

Comment: have you tried `map-service-api.test/test` ? is this web.php or api.php ?

Comment: Could you post your `api.php` file content?

Comment: Could you please provide `php artisan route:list` here?

Comment: I wrote in api.php file

Answer (score 0):

If you write this route in web.php then it should be

```
http://map-service-api.test/test
```

If you write this route in api.php then it should be

```
http://map-service-api.test/api/test
```